# Product object is missing in sandbox

Tags: administration, licenses, admin

In My Sandbox i don't see the product and price book standard object.

i was not able find any solution from online/article how to enable the feature.  Even my scratch org i can see the product standard object without any external feature enbaled.

Organization Edition :  Enterprise Edition

ANy help, How enable product object in sandbox ?

[image]

Comment: Did you check the lightning Object Manager?

Comment: @J.Schreiber Thank you...  such  a small thing missed out..